# How to count the number of character differences between two files?

Tags: linux, diff, git-diff

How to count the number of character differences between two files on Linux command line?

Comment: What do you need that for?

Comment: just need to count them...

Answer (score 0):

It can be done with `git diff` and `pcre2grep` (part of `pcre2-utils` on Linux)

```
git diff --patience --word-diff=porcelain --word-diff-regex=. file1 file2 | pcre2grep -M "^@[\s\S]*" | pcre2grep -M --file-offsets "(^-.*\n)(^\+.*\n)?|(^\+.*\n)" | wc -l
```